# Both Chrome and Firefox not loading particular page item

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

The website Harpers.org has a login button in the upper left corner of its pages that does not load in either my Firefox or Chrome browsers on my Ubuntu 20.4.06 system. Using the same wifi network, the button does load on my Android and Windows systems. Both my FF and Chrome had the Privacy Badger extension, but I've disabled it in FF and removed it completely from Chrome. Have disabled other extensions, cleared cache, restarted browsers and have also used the "refresh" function in FF's Troubleshooting mode, which [solved a similar problem for someone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399635/firefox-not-loading-a-particular-website), but didn't work here.  Any ideas?